# Yii2 validate Bank Account number and Routing number

Tags: yii2, yii2-validation

I want to validate `Bank Account number(123456789)` and `Routing number(434344343)`,
with custom `message=>Please enter 12 digit valid account number`.(000123456789)

I used number validator, integer but not working as I expecting.
Validator should checks values are numbers and also numbers length.
I check this documentation here [tutorial-core-validators](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/tutorial-core-validators.md)

```
 public function rules()
{
    return [
      [['accountnumber'], 'number', 'min' => 12, 'max'=>12],// not wokred
      [['routingnumber'], 'number', 'min' => 9, 'max'=>9], // not wokred
// then I used
  [['accountnumber', 'routingnumber', ], 'integer'] 
]
}
```

Any suggession?

Comment: This worked for me.
`['accountnumber', 'match', 'pattern'=> '/^[0-9]{12}$/i', 
'message'=> 'Please enter 12 digit valid account number.(000123456789)' ],`

Comment: `['routingnumber', 'match', 'pattern'=> '/^[0-9]{9}$/i',
    'message'=> 'Please enter 9 digit valid routing number.(110000000)'
    ],`

Comment: This is not related to your question. Did you link up the bank account using Account number, Name on an account and Routing number? If you did? then how and if not then how can I do it? That may be a silly question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `min` and `max` parameters are for the **value**, not the lenght, maybe you should save as a string.

```
['accountnumber', 'string', 'length' => [12, 12]
```

And also add a regular expression:

```
['accountnumber', 'match', 'pattern' => '/^[0-9]*$/i']
```

Comment: Let me check, your second line of code will work, I think

Comment: @MuhammadShahzad I coudn't check it, but the right code wouldn't be very different.

Comment: This worked for me. `['accountnumber',  'match', 'pattern'=> '/^[0-9]{12}$/i',
    'message'=> 'Please enter 12 digit valid account number.(000123456789)'
    ],`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public function rules()
{
return [
  [['accountnumber'], 'string', 'min' => 12, 'max'=>12, 'message' => "Please enter 12 digit valid account number"],
  [['routingnumber'], 'string', 'min' => 9, 'max'=>9], 
  [['accountnumber', 'routingnumber', ], 'integer'], 
 ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Minimum, Maximum Number Validation

```
 public function rules(){
        return [
            [['accountnumber'],'number','min'=>10],
            [['accountnumber'],'number','max'=>100],
            [['accountnumber'],'number','min'=>10,'max'=>100],
        ];
    }
```

Minimum, Maximum String Validation

```
public function rules(){
    return [
        [['min_string'],'string','min'=>10],
        [['max_string'],'string','max'=>10],
        [['min_max_string'],'string','min'=>5,'max'=>10],
        ['min_max_string2', 'string', 'length' => [4, 10]],
    ];
}
```

Custom Validation

```
public function rules(){
    return [
        ['custom_validation','custom_function_validation', 'values'=>['One', 'Two']],
    ];
}
public function custom_function_validation($attribute, $params){
    // add custom validation
    if (!in_array($this->$attribute, $params['values'])) 
        $this->addError($attribute,'Custom Validation Error');
}
```